# How do I force lingering Preview windows to close?

Tags: preview, bug, window-manager

Recently after quitting Preview, I have a few windows from Preview that remain open, and provide no normal way to close them (Cmd-W does't work, and the close button is disabled). The only thing I can do with the windows is minimize them. Restarting Preview has no effect.

How do I force lingering Preview windows to close?

Comment: Bonus question: How could such a situation arise in the first place?

Comment: Have you restarted recently? I find this with Excel, after 6 or so days of hard use...

Comment: @SolarMike I'm looking for a solution other than restarting, of course. Just putting an app shouldn't leave windows lying around. In fact, it should be impossible for this to happen. If an app can leave windows lying around, imagine what else it could plant). There's got to be a way to find locate the process associated with those windows and terminate it.